# Spring: error when i split applicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I created ,with Eclipse Luna,a Spring MVC project (Spring +Jpa + Hibernate) and i splitted the application context in three parts:

- applicationContext-dao.xml
- applicationContext-datasource.xml
- applicationContext-servlet.xml

If i use only one file.xml the project works but if i split in three file i have always this error.How can i solve it?
Thanks

Error code:

```
Grave: Allocate exception for servlet applicationContext
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:515)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:682)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:655)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>SpringStore</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping> 

<context-param>
  <param-name>ContextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
    applicationContext-servlet.xml
    applicationContext-datasource.xml
    applicationContext-dao.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean  class="daoJPA.ClienteDAOImpl" id="clienteDAO"/>
</beans>
```

applicationContext-datasource.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName"/>
    <property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_store" name="url"/>
    <property value="root" name="username"/>
    <property value="password" name="password"/>
    <property value="5" name="initialSize"/>
    <property value="10" name="maxTotal"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your web.xml. If you're only going to use the DispatcherServlet, then you need to add the configuration files as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
                     applicationContext-servlet.xml
                     applicationContext-datasource.xml
                     applicationContext-dao.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this case, all your Spring beans are defined in the same web application context (even if they're declared in separate files).

If you want to split your configuration into root web application context and a child web application, then you typically define your Controller/MVC beans in the child context and your non-MVC beans in root context. This is done as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/applicationContext-datasource.xml
        WEB-INF/applicationContext-dao.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note that your Spring configuration files should go under WEB-INF folder (or a subdirectory under it - specify the file location accordingly).

For an explanation of the difference between root application context and (child) web application context, see [this explanation](http://www.softwarevol.com/en/tutorial/Spring-ContextLoaderListener-And-DispatcherServlet-Concepts).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use your configuration like below,Let say your final configuration file is applicationContext.xml,which contains further three configuration file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="applicationContext-datasource.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-servlet.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-dao.xml" />
</beans>
```

And contextConfiguration value will be in web.xml would be like below.

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```